# Configure Apache to redirect everything from port 80 to another domain

Tags: apache, redirect

I usually program that in Django but it makes more sense to do it in Apache. I need every request to whatever domain that comes to port 80 to get redirected to another domain (on port 80) but requests coming to any other port should still come in. It must not be a permanent redirect. How would I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I set my virtual host in Apache to listen to port 80, I don't need to tell the redirection directive to listen to that port so I just need to add that to the virtual host listening to port 80:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ http://other-domain.com/ [R=302,L]
```